# Multiple Minimum Values in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe of multiple minimum values but the min functions picks only one on the column.

```
 ABCD     0.000000
 JKLM     0.016535
 CAN1     0.381729
 MET2     0.275013
 INDI     0.149280
 MAN3     0.000000
```

`temp2.ix[temp2.idxmin()]` only picks one value that is ABCD with 0.0

I would like to fetch both ABCD and MAN3 as minimum ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use following:

```
df[df == df.min()].dropna()

In [49]: df[df == df.min()].dropna()
Out[49]:
    1
0
ABCD  0
MAN3  0
```

Answer (score 3):

Next solution is:

```
df.where(df == df.min()).dropna()
```

And [`df.idxmin()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html) return only one value, because:

> This method is the DataFrame version of ndarray.argmin.

And [`ndarray.argmin`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.argmin.html) explain this situation in [doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html#numpy.argmin):

> In case of multiple occurrences of the minimum values, the indices corresponding to the first occurrence are returned.

Comment: @Anu - Use `df2 = df[df.groupby('A')['C'].transform('min') == df['C']]`

Answer (score 1):

Compare the minimum value for Boolean indexing

```
df
Out[42]: 
             b
a             
ABCD  0.000000
JKLM  0.016535
CAN1  0.381729
MET2  0.275013
INDI  0.149280
MAN3  0.000000

df[df.b == df.b.min()]
Out[43]: 
      b
a      
ABCD  0
MAN3  0
```