# How to get the indexes of all minimum values in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 0, 1], 'B': [1, 0, 0]}, index=['x', 'y', 'z'])

   A  B
x  0  1
y  0  0
z  1  0
```

For each row, I want the names of all the columns with the lowest value (edit: per row), something like:

```
x  A
y  A
y  B
z  B

# or 

x  [A]
y  [A, B]
z  [B]
```

I know `idxmin()` gives the first instance of the lowest value:

```
df.idxmin(axis=1)

x    A
y    A
z    B
```

But what is an efficient way to get all of them?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34014137/multiple-minimum-values-in-pandas-dataframe) gives all of the rows with the minimum *value* in a specific column, but that's not quite what I want.

Edit: Here's a better toy df to play with for getting the column names with the minimum value in each row:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 0, 6], 'B': [3, 0, 2]}, index=['x', 'y', 'z'])

   A  B
x  1  3
y  0  0
z  6  2
```

Comment: Upvote because you found `df.idxmin`

Comment: Should the minimum be per group of overall?

Comment: @mozway the minimum per row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`+`transform('min')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
s = df.stack()
s[s.eq(s.groupby(level=0).transform('min'))]
```

Output:

```
x  A    0
y  A    0
   B    0
z  B    0
```

Alternative format:

```
s = df.stack()
(s[s.eq(s.groupby(level=0).transform('min'))]
  .reset_index()
  .groupby('level_0')['level_1'].apply(list)
 )
```

Output:

```
level_0
x       [A]
y    [A, B]
z       [B]
Name: level_1, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for this. what does level=-1 do in groupby? (It also seems like levels 1 and 0 both give the same result, for this toy example at least.)

Comment: This means the last (right) level of the multindex ;)

Comment: @hmg I did a mistake, it should be level 0 to get the min per row. Level -1 would get the min per column (coincidentally identical here)

Answer (score 2):

Convert the df into bool by finding every min value and pull columns that return True into a list

```
 s= df==df.min()

df['column_min']=s.agg(lambda s: s.index[s].values, axis=1)




 A   B   column_min
x  0  1        [A]
y  0  0     [A, B]
z  1  0        [B]
```

Comment: OP clarified the requirements, you need to use a `groupby` to get the min per row ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is a one-liner, similar to @mozway's second solution but uses a boolean mask similar to @wwnde's:

```
min_cols = df.eq(df.min(axis=1), axis=0).stack().groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.index.get_level_values(1)[x].tolist())
```

Output:

```
x       [A]
y    [A, B]
z       [B]
```